# Integral bounded below

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

A function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by
\begin{equation*}
f(x) := \int_{1}^{x^2} e^{t^2} \; dt.
\end{equation*}
Is $f$ bounded below?
$f$ is bounded below if there is an $m\in \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)\geq m$, $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$.
The answer is yes it is bounded below by $f(0) = -\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$.
My question is how do you get this value and how do you use the above definition to show this? Thanks.

Comment: it's obvious the minimum is at 0, but I'm skeptical one can compute it to be that exactly (in fact, i don't think that's correct)

Comment: $$f(0)\ne-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2$$

Comment: $f(0) = -\frac {\sqrt {\pi}}{2} \text {erfi}(1)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly $f(x)$ is even. That is to say $f(x)=f(-x)$. Then we have
$$f'(x)=2xe^{x^4}\gt0\qquad\forall x\gt0$$
Hence $f(x)$ has a global minimum at $x=0$. This is because $f(x)$ would appear 'bowl-like' (it increases away from $f(0)$ when $x$ tends in either direction from $x=0$) if sketched on a plane. Hence $f(x)\ge f(0)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So when you say "bowl-like" do you mean like a parabola $y = x^2$ because I'm told to sketch this we solve $x^2 = 1$.

Comment: Yes, like that except when $x=0$, $f(x)\lt0$. Also $f(\pm1)=0$.

Comment: Right so sketch $x^2=1$ and shade where $x^2<1$ and where $x^2>1$.

Comment: Both. Having a little trouble on both I should’ve probably asked both questions in the thread sorry for the confusion

Comment: Clearly $e^{t^2}\gt0$ for all $t$. So, when integrated over bounds $[a,b]$ where $b\gt a$ we must have that the result is positive. Similarly if the bounds are such that $b\lt a$ the result would be negative. This allows one to deduce that $f(x)\gt0$ whenever $x^2\gt1$ and $f(x)\lt0$ whenever $x^2\lt1$. If $a=b$ then clearly the result is $0$ so we have $f(x)=0$ whenever $x^2=1$. This and the facts that $f(x)$ is even (mirrored over $y$-axis) and strictly increasing for $x\gt0$ should be sufficient to sketch $f(x)$.

Comment: So $f(x)$ is the parabola $f(x)=x^2$ so $f$ is decreasing between the line $1$ and $x^2$ . Thank you very much. Is there anyway you can upload a sketch I want to compare with mine???

Comment: @squenshl It looks like [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kbpvphqxue). Ignore the horizontal lines because Desmos cannot evaluate the function as it increases so fast.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \text{erfi}(x^2) - \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \text{erfi}(1)$$
where $$ \text{erfi}(y) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^y \exp(t^2)\; dt$$
Since $\text{erfi}(x^2) \ge 0$ the minimum value 
$$ -\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \text{erfi(1)} = - \int_0^1 \exp(t^2)\; dt$$
occurs at $x=0$.  $\text{erfi}$ is a "well-known" special function, but not an elementary one.  You could expand the exponential in a Maclaurin series and integrate term-by-term, so

$$ f(0) = -1 - \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{10} - \frac{1}{42} - \ldots = - \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+1)k!}$$

But it's certainly not $-\sqrt{\pi}/2$.  Numerically, $f(0) \approx -1.462651746$ while $-\sqrt{\pi}/2 \approx -0.8862269255$.